# Eclipse debugger crashing because of JOptionPane

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, joptionpane

When I run the debugger with a print line in it runs fine, but as soon as i put a joptionpane method in it crashes. i imported javax.swing.joptionpane.

```
Integer.parseInt(String, int) line: 470 
Integer.parseInt(String, int) line: 470 
Integer.parseInt(String) line: 499  
AquaOptionPaneUI(BasicOptionPaneUI).getMnemonic(String, Locale) line: 806   
AquaOptionPaneUI(BasicOptionPaneUI).getButtons() line: 773 [local variables unavailable]    
AquaOptionPaneUI(BasicOptionPaneUI).createButtonArea() line: 613 [local variables     unavailable]  
AquaOptionPaneUI.createButtonArea() line: 33 [local variables unavailable]  
AquaOptionPaneUI(BasicOptionPaneUI).installComponents() line: 161 [local variables unavailable] 
AquaOptionPaneUI(BasicOptionPaneUI).installUI(JComponent) line: 124 
JOptionPane(JComponent).setUI(ComponentUI) line: 662        
JOptionPane.setUI(OptionPaneUI) line: 1837  
JOptionPane.updateUI() line: 1859 [local variables unavailable] 
JOptionPane.<init>(Object, int, int, Icon, Object[], Object) line: 1822 
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Component, Object, String, int, Icon, Object[], Object) line: 552   
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Component, Object, String, int) line: 508   
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Component, Object) line: 458    
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Object) line: 424   
debugtest.main(String[]) line: 15
```

Comment: Did you have a question, code..?  As it stands, this adds up to 'not a real question'.

Comment: @AndrewThompson how do i get debugger to work. the simple line     response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input a number greater than 1:"); caused the debugger to crash.

Comment: I don't use Eclipse.  Try hitting F1.

Comment: Ask on the Eclipse support forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

64 bit eclipse was the issues, once i downloaded the 32 bit version for Mac it worked like a snake charm